# Нарушение синтаксической связи при обороте с предлогом

Tags: стилистика, управление, смысл

> Кроме материальных потерь, гроссмейстер находился еще в сильном цейтноте. [Розенталь Д.Э., Практическая стилистика русского языка (Изд. 5-е), 1987]

Тоесть, получается, что потери принадлежат кому-то другому, а не гроссмейстеру. Мое исправление ошибки в предложении.

**Гроссмейстер находился в сильном цейтноте кроме материальных потерь.**

Здесь я исправил синтаксическую связь при обороте с предлогом **кроме**: глагол *находился* не управлял упомянутым оборотом.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлог *кроме* может использоваться только с двумя однородными object + object.

Правильная схема:

Гроссмейстер находился object + кроме + object

Поскольку глагол находиться не вяжется с цейтнотом и с материальными потерями одновременно, то заменяем его на глагол быть:

У гроссмейстера был object + кроме + object

подставляя object'ы получаем:

> У гроссмейстера был кроме материальных потерь еще и сильный цейтнот.

В русском языке обычно можно безнаказанно менять порядок слов, так что имеем:

> Кроме материальных потерь, у гроссмейстера был сильный цейтнот.

Ну или так:

> Кроме того что у первого гроссмейстера были материальные потери у второго гроссмейстера пропал аппетит.

или

> Кроме материальных потерь гроссмейстер нес временные.